# Как удалить обьект из бд, на сайте на Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Гуглил. Нашел способ [в этой статье](https://www.rubyplus.com/articles/2811-Rails-5-Basics-Delete-Article), но не помогло.
часть вьюхи

```
<!-- 4 не работающих способа -->
<%= link_to 'Destroy', client, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %><!-- автосгенерированный скаффолдом -->
<%= link_to 'Destroy', client_path(client), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %><!-- предложенный [статьей][1] -->
<a href="http://localhost:3000/clients/<%= client.id%>/destroy">Destroy</a>
<!-- были мысли, что какая-то из этих ссылок сгенерируется при превращении link_to в код на html -->
<a href="http://localhost:3000/clients/<%= client.id%>/delete">Destroy</a>
```

первые два способа просто показывают клиента, но не удаляют его, последние два генерируют Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/clients/2/destroy" или No route matches [GET] "/clients/2/delete"
часть контроллера

```
def destroy
  @client.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to clients_url }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

команда rake routes выдает [image: такие пути]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3-й и 4-й способы потребуют от вас написания дополнительного кода в контроллере, но я бы их не использовал. Они семантически некорректны - `GET`-запросы не должны менять ресурс. В случае с удалением ресурса, целесообразно использовать `DELETE`-запросы.

2-й способ в вашем случае идентичен первому, так как в роутах у вас указано `resources :clients` без нестандартных параметров и без дополнительной вложенности.

1-й способ написан корректно, но чтобы он работал - вам нужно подключить в проекте (в `application.js`) небольшое js-решение от Rails:

- Для Rails 5.1 это `rails-ujs`
- Для Rails ранних версий - `jquery_ujs`

Подключите нужную библиотеку в вашем `application.js`:

```
//= require rails-ujs
```

, и убедитесь, что в вашем собственном `javascript` коде нет ошибок, так как их наличие может мешать выполнению кода в `rails-ujs`. Обычно такие ошибки можно увидеть в инспекторе объектов вашего браузера (например в Google Chrome на вкладке Console).

Comment: О, они его наконец-то отвязали от jQuery! Йу-у-уху-у!

Comment: А где можно почитать про rails-ujs?

Comment: @Colibri, подойдут любые старые доки и статьи по jquery_ujs. rails-ujs - то же самое, только с некоторыми исправленными багами и без jquery в зависимостях. Интерфейс же не изменился.

Comment: @Colibri [исходный код](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actionview/app/assets/javascripts) довольно неплох.