# Ruby On Rails 5. Не обрабатывает запрос PATCH

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Добрый день.

В "рельсах" я новичок, поэтому буду задавать глупые вопросы ))

У меня проблема с **Rails 5.1**, казалось бы, в самом неожиданном месте...

Имеем контроллер **`TestsController`** и модель **`Test`** в БД.
Пытаюсь создать для них стандартные маршруты (**routes.rb**):

```
resources :tests
```

Маршруты создаются:

```
tests       GET     /tests(.:format)            tests#index
            POST    /tests(.:format)            tests#create
new_test    GET     /tests/new(.:format)        tests#new
edit_test   GET     /tests/:id/edit(.:format)   tests#edit
test        PATCH   /tests/:id(.:format)        tests#update
            PUT     /tests/:id(.:format)        tests#update
            DELETE  /tests/:id(.:format)        tests#destroy
```

`Index` и `new`/`create` работают, как и должны, а вот с `edit`/`update` вопрос.

Форма редактирования:

```
<%= form_with model: @test do |form| %>
...
```

Вроде даже формирует правильный `html`, в соответствии с документацией:

```
<form action="/tests/288" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" />
    ...
```

Но при отправке запроса, я всегда получаю ошибку:

```
No route matches [POST] "/tests/288"
```

Т.е. запрос, по идее должен обработаться в **Rails**, как `PATCH`, но этого не происходит, он всегда воспринимается, как `POST`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно проверить, чтобы все-таки заработал `PATCH`?

**UPD**

Согласно [посту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/666372/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-rails-5), предлагается подключить к проекту `rails-ujs`, что я и сделал. Однако ошибку это не исправило, она по прежнему есть, но теперь в javascript:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/tests/289 404 (Not Found)
Rails.ajax @ application-a4b54ac3a3b7244f9d4baffe76072e24d3eaea04129b5eac919dc5ad4ab1233d.js:844
Rails.handleRemote @ application-a4b54ac3a3b7244f9d4baffe76072e24d3eaea04129b5eac919dc5ad4ab1233d.js:1201
(anonymous) @ application-a4b54ac3a3b7244f9d4baffe76072e24d3eaea04129b5eac919dc5ad4ab1233d.js:801
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как удалить обьект из бд, на сайте на Rails 5?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/666372/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8c%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b1%d0%b4-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-rails-5)

Comment: В рельсы, начиная с 5.1, этот гем встроен, так что дело вряд ли в нём.